# Managed Package: Prevent Push Upgrade but from subscriber's org side

Tags: managed-package, subscriber, push-upgrade

Looking for a way to block push upgrade (prevent from happening) but from the subscriber's org side, i.e. let client manage package version manually.

As a package provider when we are pushing upgrades there is a bunch of options to limit to specific subset of orgs (based on ids, org types etc.) or just push to all of them excluding specified list of org ids.

But what we need now is an ability for subscriber orgs to turn off push upgrades on their side, i.e. for org itself to say kinda "I'm not ready" or "Do not disturb", "Leave me alone" etc.

The only idea I've come up so far is to add some logic to post install script and fail push upgrade based on certain condition, e.g. check values of some custom settings etc.

Wondering what other options could be here, if any.